# Как исправить ошибку компиляции в pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я подозреваю, что ошибка связана с кириллицей в имени пользователя, но не могу сменить его из-за ОС windows 8.1...

````
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xf1' in file C:\Users\Стас\AppData\L
ocal\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no
 encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details.```

Можно как-то исправить это, не меняя имя пользователя?
````

Comment: А файл у вас в кодировке `UTF-8`? Если да, то проблем с кириллицей быть не должно. Если файл в другой кодировке, например `CP-1251`, то переведите его в `UTF-8`, ну либо задайте кодировку специальным комментарием в первой строке, чтобы питон её знал.

Comment: проблему решило изменение имени пользователя и полная переустановка python.
спасибо за совет.